# Qt : Can't update QQuickWidget from outside MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have been trying to fix this issue for 2 days now.I have a gmaps QML project , which I've Integrated into my Qt widgets project using the following code:

```
gmap locator;
ui->quickWidget->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/maps/main.qml"));

ui->quickWidget->rootContext()->setContextProperty("gmap",&locator);
ui->quickWidget->show();
```

When I set the location on the map from the MainWindow using

```
    locator.setData( "28.6082819", "77.0350079");
```

It works as expected , however , when I add a toolbutton and do the same thing from its slot , it doesn't work.I've connected it to a custom slot in my MainWindow like this:

```
   connect(ui->toolButton_5, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(plotmap(QString(ui->lineEdit_3->text()),QString(ui->lineEdit_4->text()),&locator,&ui->quickWidget)));
```

and here's the custom slot:

```
    void MainWindow::plotmap(QString lat , QString lon, gmap *loc,QQuickWidget *view)
{
  
       loc->setData("02.60","77.04");
       view->show();
       view->update();


}
```

Here's my qml files

**gmap.cpp**

```
    #include "gmap.h"

gmap::gmap()
{

}

void gmap::setData(QString lat,QString lang)
{
    qDebug(lat.toLatin1());

    emit getLat(lat.toDouble());
    emit getLang(lang.toDouble());
}
```

**gmap.h**

```
    #ifndef GMAP_H
#define GMAP_H

#include <QObject>

class gmap : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT


public:
    gmap();


signals:
    void getLat(double lat);
    void getLang(double lang);


public slots:
    void setData(QString lat,QString lang);



};
#endif // GMAP_H
```

**main.qml**

```
    import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2;
import QtPositioning 5.6;
import QtLocation 5.9
import Qt3D.Input 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2;


Window {
    width: Qt.platform.os == "android" ? Screen.width : 512
    height: Qt.platform.os == "android" ? Screen.height : 512
    visible: true

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"
        PluginParameter {
             name: 'osm.mapping.highdpi_tiles'
            value: !!1      }
    }

    Connections{

        target: gmap
        onGetLat : mapmarker.center.latitude = lat

    }
    Connections{

        target: gmap
        onGetLang : mapmarker.center.longitude = lang

    }
    Connections{

        target: gmap
        onGetLang : map.center = QtPositioning.coordinate(mapmarker.center.latitude,mapmarker.center.longitude,150);



    }

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.rightMargin: -15
        anchors.bottomMargin: -10
        anchors.leftMargin: 15
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate() // NSUT
        zoomLevel: 14
        activeMapType: supportedMapTypes[2]


        Button {
            x: 389
            y: 445
            text: "ADD MARKER"
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 27
            anchors.rightMargin: 23
            padding: 7
            onClicked: gmap.setData(textField.text,textField1.text)
        }



        MapCircle {

            id: mapmarker
                center {
                    latitude: 28.6078
                    longitude: 77.0406


                }
                radius: 50.0
                color: 'green'
                border.width: 3
        }


        TextField {
            id: textField
            x: 176
            y: 397
            text: qsTr("")
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 75
            anchors.rightMargin: 136
        }

        TextField {
            id: textField1
            x: 176
            y: 445
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 27
            anchors.rightMargin: 136
            font.hintingPreference: Font.PreferDefaultHinting
        }


    }

}
```

The map in my QQuickWidget doesn't update.What could I be doing wrong , please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK your connect syntax is wrong.

Store `locator` as a member somewhere, in MainWindow for example:

```
public:
    void setLocator(gmap* loc) { m_locator = loc; }

private:
    gmap* m_locator;
```

Add a slot to MainWindow:

```
private slot:
    plotmapFromLineEdits() { plotmap(ui->lineEdit_3->text(), ui->lineEdit_4->text(), m_locator, ui->quickWidget); }
```

and connect it like this:

```
connect(ui->toolButton_5, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(plotmapFromLineEdits()));
```

Or in C++11 or above you can connect without defining a slot by using lambda:

```
connect(ui->toolButton_5, SIGNAL(clicked()), [&](){plotmap(ui->lineEdit_3->text(), ui->lineEdit_4->text(), m_locator, ui->quickWidget);}));
```

I don't think you have to `show` and `update` QQuickWidget every time. Just delete the quickwidget parameter.

Lastly please make sure your class names start with an `uppercase` letter:
gmap => GMap